# Python function to get all inner values on JSON

Tags: python, json, dictionary

```
data_dict = {
  "foo1": "bar1",
  "foo2": [{"bar2": "koko"}, {"bar3": "koko2"} ],
  "foo3": {
     "foo4": "bar4",
     "foo5": {
        "foo6": "bar6",
        "foo7": "bar7",
     },
  }
}
```

I need a Python function that get JSON and path of keys string like `"foo2[0].bar2"` and return from dict the `data_dict[foo2][0][bar2]` no matter if its an inner list/dict and no matter how many keys to get.
there is some external package in Python for this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into [jmespath](https://pypi.org/project/jmespath/)-

```
pip install jmespath
import jmespath

data_dict = {
  "foo1": "bar1",
  "foo2": [{"bar2": "koko"}, {"bar3": "koko2"} ],
  "foo3": {
     "foo4": "bar4",
     "foo5": {
        "foo6": "bar6",
        "foo7": "bar7",
     },
  }
}

print(jmespath.search('foo2[0].bar2' , data_dict))

>> koko
```

[jmespath tutorials](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

Parse the path into keys and indices.

```
key = "foo2[0].bar2"
keys = tuple(
    int(x) if x.isdigit() else x
    for x in key.replace("[", ".").replace("]", "").split(".")
)

curr = data_dict
for k in keys:
    curr = curr[k]
print(curr)
# koko
```